# the variable which is define inside ng-init not reflecting changes through out the view in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following code:

```
<div ng-init="showLogin=true;">
    <div ng-if="showLogin">
       <span> show login value is:{{showLogin}} </span>////here value is true after click on create an accoun 
        <form class="login-form">
         ............
         ............
         <div class="create-account">
            <p>
                 Don't have an account yet ?&nbsp; <a href=""  ng-click="showLogin=false;">
                 {{showLogin}}
                Create an account </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="showLogin">
        <span> show login value is:{{showLogin}} </span>//here value is true after click on create an accoun 
        <form class="registration-form">
         ............
         ............
         <div class="create-account">
            <p>
                <a href=""  ng-click="showLogin=true;">Login </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

initially it shows both login and registration page. so it is fine according to the code. but when i click on **Create an account** both form should be hide but still no form get hide.the value of showLogin just above login form is false and just above registration form is true.i don't know where i am doing wrong step. if you have any idea to solve this issue  please suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ng-init if you can help it, the variable may be local.

instead initialize the value in your controller:

```
$scope.showLogin = true;
```

And when you want to flip the state, use functions:

```
<a href=""  ng-click="showLogin=true;">Login </a> // Change this
<a href=""  ng-click="changeShowLogin(true)">Login </a> // To something like this

$scope.changeShowLogin = function(value){
   $scope.showLogin = value;
}
```